How to run custom jobs before inheriting from an immutable YAML template
We want to add the following snippet before inheriting from an immutable YAML that does the build job.
jobs:
  - job: PreBuild
    timeoutInMinutes: 120
    pool:
      name: 'poolname'
      vmImage: 'windows'
      steps:
        - checkout: self
          clean: true
          persistCredentials: true
        - task: ..........
          ......
        - task: ..........
          ......

But when we add the snippet before the extends, the YAML would prompt: Unexpected value 'extends'
extends:
  template: template.yml@TemplateRepo

So what is the best solution based on the immutable build templates to have us run several tasks before inheriting the template where template jobs always execute first?
Or, are there any other approaches that we could have everything inheriting inside the template but have our custom steps run first?

The general approach is to negotiate with the owner of the "immutable" template to mutate it slightly in order to accept a stepList, jobList, or stageList parameter (depending on your requirements). It's common to have, for example, optional preBuildSteps and postBuildSteps parameters that accept a stepList in order to pass in steps that run before and after a build.
If it's truly immutable inasmuch as the team that owns the template will not implement such a pattern, then you won't be able to extend the template and still fulfill your requirements.

Thank you Daniel. I had a quick attempt on the answer Kevin offered below but sadly the parent template.yml uses extends in itself so it's kinda nested. It seems that negotiating with the owners is the only option.

Refer to this doc: Template usage reference

Extends template control what is allowed in a pipeline. When an extends template controls what is allowed in a pipeline, the template defines logic that another file must follow.

When you use the extends template in YAML pipeline, we are not able to add additional tasks/jobs to the YAML pipeline.  It supports to defining the key word in the YAML root level. For example: triggers, variables.

what is the best solution based on the immutable build templates to have us run several tasks before inheriting the template where template jobs always execute first?

To meet your requirement, you can change to use - template field to use the YAML template(include template) and define the job at the same time.
For example:
Template is job level:
jobs:
- job: PreBuild
  timeoutInMinutes: 120
  pool:
    name: 'poolname'
    vmImage: 'windows'
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        clean: true
        persistCredentials: true
  .....

- template: template.yml@TemplateRepo


Thank you Kevin! However the immutable parent template.yml is having extends inside itself so it still failed with the same error (but went to parent template).

@xchen218 In this case, if we use template.yml in YAML  pipeline, we will not be able to add the extra steps/jobs. It should be a good choice to communicate to the template owner to use include template.
